# ModelBuilder for listing and exporting GDB contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I currently generate a list of the feature classes in a gdb using a submodel with a feature class iterator and use Collect Values to make a multivalue list of the fc names.

My problem comes with trying to send the list to Conversion Tools-->To Shapefile-->Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple) as it only accepts Feature Layers as input.  I am unable to figure out how to manufacture multiple feature layers from the Collect Values output parameter from the submodel.

Comment: Most of your question is background to your actual problem so I think you need to focus it on where you are stuck.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to include a test model that will take "a semicolon-separated list of the fc names [and] get the user to be able to pick from this list and then send the list to Conversion Tools-->To Shapefile-->Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple)", please?  Once you get that working you can plug it back into your larger model.

Comment: OK.  I'll edit the OP now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the interactive picking, but you could use a 'Feature Classes' iterator, and then make a list from the 'names' box, and then pass that to your user. How to let people pick, I can't speculate. Once you've got the list they want, use a 'Multivalue' iterator for all those filenames, and export them.

Comment: Um, no, this needs to be a single geoprocessing service.  Start the service, look at the current list of gdb feature classes, pick the ones you want, and the service then exports, zips, and ships.

I've already got a submodel that lists the feature classes (discussed in the original post).  Problem is how to turn the multivalue text list of feature classes output from the submodel into something that will allow the picking and exporting.